# Org agenda tags-todo items not working

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, debug-on-error

I have some custom agenda views defined like this:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("n" "Agenda and all TODOs"
         ((agenda "" nil)
          (alltodo "" nil))
         nil)
        ("x" "personal only" tags-todo "+CATEGORY=\"personal\"" nil)
        ("h" "holding only" tags-todo "holding" nil)
        ("w" "Work stuff"
         ((agenda "" nil)
          (tags-todo "-holding-CATEGORY=\"personal\"" nil))
         nil)
        ))
```

Lately (the past month or so), if I try to view any of the three that use `tags-todo`, it fails to load. I get this error message:

`org-element--current-element: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil`

I've tried running `toggle-debug-on-error` but I don't get a traceback from this error.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this error or how I could fix it?

(or thoughts on why `toggle-debug-on-error` isn't working?)

Comment: Using `toggle-debug-on-error` flips the value of the variable `debug-on-error` which you can check with `C-h v debug-on-error` to make sure that it is `t` (if not, toggle it again and check). In addition, you should probably say `M-x top-level` to make sure that you are not in a recursive editing level where backtraces might not be shown. Then try to reproduce the problem. I hope that helps you get a backtrace which is really essential for figuring out what is going on.

Comment: I had previously confirmed that `debug-on-error` was `t` but top-level is new to me.

I ran `M-x top-level` and emacs completely hung until I killed it. After restarting, I enabled `debug-on-error` and confirmed I was at top-level... and my agenda views worked as expected! So, they're working now but I don't know what the underlying issue was.

Comment: OK - it seems that your emacs session was somewhat curdled. But all's well that ends well!